# How do i create Account on hedera testnet?

Tags: account, hedera-hashgraph

I am having issues creating account on Hedera testnet. below is the error message

> C:\Users\OJI\Documents\Hedera-test\node_modules@hashgraph\sdk\lib\Executable.cjs:666
> throw new Error(`max attempts of ${maxAttempts.toString()} was reached for request with last error being: ${persistentError != null ? persistentError.toString() : ""}`);
> ^

Error: max attempts of 10 was reached for request with last error being: BUSY
at AccountCreateTransaction.execute (C:\Users\OJI\Documents\Hedera-test\node_modules@hashgraph\sdk\lib\Executable.cjs:666:11)
at async environmentSetup (C:\Users\OJI\Documents\Hedera-test\index.js:37:24)

I tried to run "npm start" and I got the error. I was expecting an output like...

> New account ID: [newly_created_account_id]
> New account balance: 1000 tinybars.

Comment: Hey @Oji what is the script that you are running? (When you run `npm start` what is being run?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supose to run the script like "node index.js" or "node [namdeOfFile.js]" not npm

Try running your script in the temrinal like so

```
node index.js
```